# @OneToMany and different primary key

Tags: java, jpa, primary-key, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have small problem with JPA. I have three tables (OTHER table is not relevant here, but I add it just to explain why there is table USERS without PK):

```
ADDRESS
id (PK)
user_id (FK)
street

USERS
users_id(FK)
name_of_user

OTHER
users_id (PK)
```

And those are my java files:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ADDRESS")
public class Address {

@Id
@Column(name="ADDRESS_ID")
private long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="address", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
private List<Users> users;

}
```

And second one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class Users {

@Id
@Column
private long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinColumn(name="USERS_ID")
private Address address;

}
```

What I want to do? I want to fetch all users connected with certain address (One address can have many users). Problem is that Users entity doesn't have reference to address_id only to users_id. How I can tell that it should use users_id (from Address table) as a reference key, not id?

Thank you very much for help.

PS: I removed getters/setters etc. Tables of course contain more information but it's not relevant here.
PPS: I can't change anything in those tables.
PPPS: I reduce complexity of the logic behind this system, because it's too big to explain it here. So please, don't think about: Is it logical and properly designed? It is in both case, I just make it as simple as can be.

Best regards,
MicNeo

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem in your table. The address table looks like it's in a many-to-one relationship to the user, since each address references one user. That means the user is in a one-to-many relationship with the address, the opposite of what you want. You should either invert the relationship or make it a many-to-many, for which you will need a third table to map one user with one address. Finally, your entity should be called `User`, not `Users`. It represents one user, not many.

Comment: First: I can't change tables. This is existing system. Second: I think I wasn't to clear, please see that diagram: [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/xye2ccuvrf65y3e/Screenshot%202014-01-29%2019.44.21.png[/link] Please don't focus on names etc. Also, please don't bother to understand it, if it's logic for you or not. It's big system, and explaining logic behind that would take forever, so I made short version of it. Third: I didn't mentioned that in my question but Users.id is not PK. It's foreign key from different table. So to summarize, I need to map such existing tables.

Comment: You're going to have to fix your SO and be more specific in your explanation then. I don't care about understanding your existing system, but your example is quite unclear, and that I'd like to understand. From the diagram (by the way, you should fix the link) it still looks like each "USERS" can have many addresses, not the other way around. Bother to explain?

Comment: No imo, diagram [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xye2ccuvrf65y3e/Screenshot%202014-01-29%2019.44.21.png) clearly shows relation one-to-many. One Address can have many Users. And that's whole point. I feel that real question is, can I in JPA tell entity to use foreign key in jointable?

Comment: You still haven't explained where this one-to-many relationship comes from.

Comment: What do you mean? You want to know why it has to be one-to-many?

Comment: No I want to know how it is mapped in the DB. How is the relationship specified?

Comment: One entry in Address table can have many entries in Users table. I don't know if that's what you asked for ;) One more thing, database exists before I started developing application with JPA. So database it's not generated anyhow from jpa schema.

Comment: How do you retrieve the list of users per address? What's the foreign key in the users table?

Comment: For now, java code use sql queries to fetch data (not everywhere but in general). So, for example, for this case we fetch data with query: select USERS.* from ADDRESS left join USERS on ADDRESS.users_id=USERS.users_id where ADDRESS.id=<address id>. This query return all users for particular address entry.

Comment: That looks like a many-to-many relationship to me, at least from the point of view of JPA: a one to many has the form A(aid)->B(bid,aid_fk), while a many-to-many has the form A(aid)->R(aid_fk,bid_fk)<-B(bid), where R is the relationship table that links A and B in the m2m. Your "USERS" table looks a lot like the R table. This is because since the field users_id is not a PK in either USERS or ADDRESS, many records in USERS might map to one address and, viceversa, many addresses might map to one record in users.

Comment: PS: I am not able to help you without a little bit more information about your data model. You are being very cryptic.

Comment: Yes, I know that I'm not sharing too much information, but I just can't :/ Let's go to more abstract then. Forget about address, users etc. What about such situation: A(a_id, m_id_FK)<-M(m_id)-U(u_id,m_id_FK)->E(e_id,u_id_FK)  That's whole thing. Like you see, a lot's of tables take part in it. What's more, u_id in constrained by m_id, and e_id is constrained by u_id. I hope that this will bring some light over here.

Answer (score 1):

The mapping isn't correct.
If you want that address has many users, your table should look as follows.

```
ADDRESS
id
address

USERS
id
name_of_user
adess_id
```

And your mapping should be so.
Do not forget you need to instantiate the list of users.

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn (name = "ADRESS_ID")
    private Address address;

}

@Entity
@Table (name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @Column (name = "address_id")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "address", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List <User> users;

    public Address(){
        users = new ArrayList<User>();
    }

}
```

Comment: First: I can't change tables. This is existing system. Second: I think I wasn't to clear, please see that diagram: [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/xye2ccuvrf65y3e/Screenshot%202014-01-29%2019.44.21.png[/link] Please don't focus on names etc. Also, please don't bother to understand it, if it's logic for you or not. It's big system, and explaining logic behind that would take forever, so I made short version of it. Third: I didn't mentioned that in my question but Users.id is not PK. It's foreign key from different table. So to summarize, I need to map such existing tables.